# How to insert String variable into the String inside cy.get()

Tags: typescript, ecmascript-6, automated-tests, cypress

I am using Cypress with Typescript and es6:

[image]

and I have defined const inside a test:

```
const folderName = "Test"
```

I tried to insert that `folderName` into the String inside `cy.get()` using String Substitution according to this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/01/ES6-Template-Strings#string_substitution).

```
cy.get('[name="folder-name-${folderName}"]').next().click({force: true})
```

But apparently I am doing something wrong:

[image]

I managed to have it working by doing this:

```
cy.get('[name="folder-name-' + folderName + '"]').next().click({force: true})
```

But I think there are cleaner ways to do it. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for [Template literals (Template string)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals).
It is used with backticks.

Your code should be:

```js
cy.get(`[name="folder-name-${folderName}"]`).next().click({force: true})
```